# T-SQL rotating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follows:

| OrganizationCode | PrerequisitesName | PrerequisitesValue | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFA | ppco | 1 | NULL |
| AFA | liability | 1 | NULL |

I will need a result table like this:

| OrganizationCode | IsPpco | PpcoRemarks | IsLiability | LiabilityRemarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFA | true | NULL | true | NULL |

What operator can I use in SQL Server to achieve this result ?

Comment: In SQL (the language) this is called pivoting, not rotating. Check the [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) commands

Comment: This looks like a bit like an EAV antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with PIVOT, it will group by everything on the table even if you don't select some columns. If necessary use a CTE before PIVOTING. For example, here it will group everything including PrerequisitesValue

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
    OrganizationCode VARCHAR(3),
    PrerequisitesName VARCHAR(20), 
    PrerequisitesValue INT, 
    Remarks VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('AFA', 'ppco',1, null);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('AFA', 'liability',1, null);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('XYZ', 'ppco',1, 'ppcoRemark');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('ABC', 'liability',1, 'liabilityRemark');

SELECT 
    pvt.OrganizationCode,
    CASE WHEN pvt.ppco > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end IsPpco,
    CASE WHEN pvt.ppco > 0 THEN pvt.Remarks END AS PpcoRemarks,
    CASE WHEN pvt.[liability] > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END IsLiability,
    CASE WHEN pvt.[liability] > 0 THEN pvt.Remarks END AS LiabilityRemarks
FROM 
    @t t PIVOT (COUNT(PrerequisitesName) FOR PrerequisitesName IN ([liability],[ppco])) AS pvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways you can do this: You can use the actual `PIVOT` operator, or use something like `MAX` instead (this is generally called a "crosstab pivot"; i think, someone correct me if I'm wrong, I may be using the wrong terminology here). I find the latter approach generally easier to reason about as the pivot syntax is not very straight forward. This is even more important in this case as you want to pivot values from *two* columns.

The idea is you check if the `Prereq` name is what you want, and if it is, you project it's value. Otherwise, you project `null`. The `MAX` operator will pick the value you want for the rows that match the `IIF` constraint, and the nulls will fall out of the query:

```
;with a (OrgCode, PrereqName, PrereqValue, Remarks) as
(
    select 'AFA', 'ppco', 1, cast(null as varchar(100)) union all
    select 'AFA', 'liability', 1, null 
), b as
(
    select
        OrgCode,
        IsPpco = max(iif(PrereqName = 'ppco', PrereqValue, null)),
        IsLiability = max(iif(PrereqName = 'liability', PrereqValue, null)),
        LiabilityRemarks = max(iif(PrereqName = 'liability', Remarks, null))
    from a
    group by OrgCode
)
select
    OrgCode,
    IsPpco = iif(IsPpco = 1, 'True', 'False'),
    IsLiability = iif(IsLiability = 1, 'True', 'False'),
    LiabilityRemarks
from b
```